# Hello I am new to opencv and here's my question, how to communicate with external hardware after detecting a required feature in an image?

Tags: python

My project is about looking for RGB colors in an image whichever value is greater the respective coloured led must turn on i am using raspberry pi 3b+ basically i need to control a specific pin when a specific color is detected. Thanks for looking into this question:)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit broad question.

First, you should get the average of the 3 colors of the image.
Then you should use the simple GPIO API to light up the diode.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# N, M, K are your GPIO numbers where the diode is connected.
GPIO.setup(N, GPIO.OUT)  #Red
GPIO.setup(M, GPIO.OUT)  #Green
GPIO.setup(K, GPIO.OUT)  #Blue

try:  
while True:
    color = getMostUsedColor()
    if color == `Red`
        GPIO.output(N, 1)
        GPIO.output(M, 0)
        GPIO.output(K, 0)
    elif color == `Blue`           
        GPIO.output(N, 0)
        GPIO.output(M, 1)
        GPIO.output(K, 0)
    else
        GPIO.output(N, 0)
        GPIO.output(M, 0)
        GPIO.output(K, 1)

except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

`getMostUsedColor()` is a function that you should implement for getting the color that is used the most in the frame.

It should be something like this if we assume that your frame has 3 digits for colors.

```
def getMostUsedColor():
    frame = getFreame() # from your API

    red = 0
    green = 0
    blue = 0

    for pixel in frame:
         red += pixel[0]  # or the API for getting value of the color red. It should be from 0 to 255
         green += pixel[1]
         blue += pixel[2]


    if red > blue and red > green:
         return 'Red'
    if green > blue and green > red:
         return 'Green'
    if blue > green and blue > red:
         return 'Blue'
```

Note that it this will work for small images. If you have to do it for a big image you should make sure that you'll not overflow the variables `red`, `green` and `blue`.

Comment: First of all thanks for your detailed reply you're awesome! the part which I didn't understand is the keyword pixel used in the for loop of getMostUsedColor() function how can i get the BGR array values in that variable which is undefined ?

Comment: @abhinayoja Depends on what you chose to use. There are more than a few APIs out there which will fit your needs. For example, check OpenCV and read a bit about it. You'll be able to adapt your code to this answer in no time